# set class depending on returned data

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

Morning,

I am setting the class of a td when i return data from the database to show changes/updates.
On one of the returned fields i have 4 options and i need to change the css class of that field depending on the result.

```
 "<td" + (res.prodPublished ? "" : " class='updated'") + ">" + res.prodPublished + "</td>"
```

I am currently using the above, which is ok if you have just true or false. I however have...
True, False, Processing, New.

How can i change the class, depending on these options?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why should you keep the options as seperate class and assingn the class to td

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a js function?

```
function get_cell_class(type) {
    if(type == "True") {
        return " class='updated'";
    }

    if(type == "False") {
        return " class='class_2'";
    }

    ..
}
```

Then within your HTML code:

```
"<td" + get_cell_class(res.prodPublished) + ">" + res.prodPublished + "</td>"
```

### Method 2:

Or you can just make CSS classes of the values:

```
.my_css_true {
    color: blue;
}

.my_css_updated {
    color: orange;
}
```

Then in HTML:

```
"<td class=\"my_css_" + res.prodPublished + "\">" + res.prodPublished + "</td>"
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Use a dictionary

```
var classes = {
  'True': ' class="updated"',
  'False': '',
  'New': ' class="other-classname-new"',
  'Processing': ' class="other-classname-processing"'
};

//some time later

 "<td" + classes[res.prodPublished] + ">" + res.prodPublished + "</td>"
```

note that `"True"` and `"False"` are strings, not boolean primitives. Therefore `res.prodPublished` needs to be a string too.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to setup an if else instead

You can write it as a standard if else or the same way you do now.

```
var theClass = (result == "true" ? "class for true": 
      (result == "false" ? "class for false":
              (result == "processing" ? "class for processing": "class for new")));
```

Comment: I don't think nesting shorthand ifs is a good practice, as it is much harder to read than regular if-else blocks or switches (or dictionaries as in Romans answer).

Comment: Why is it not good practice? I can't say I've ever heard that before.  I also don't think its hard to read at all.  It's different, I'll give you that but certainly no harder to read unless you are doing really complex stuff, which this deffinitely is not.

Comment: Well, I do believe that it takes more time to understand what it does when you're nesting shorthand ifs, than using regular blocks. If-else blocks has a structure that is easier to read and understand. But maybe that is just personal opinion. :)

Comment: I think it's just because you're used to standard if blocks.  If you are used to reading this style then it's just as easy as ready standard if blocks.  As I said though I only tend to use them for simple blocks such as this.